# How to calculate the range of data type float in c++?

Tags: c++, math, type-conversion

As we can see int has 4 byte in memory, that are 32bits, after applying range formula , we can see range of int -2147483648 to 2147483647. I have calculated the ranges of all datatypes besides float and double and long double. 
I dont know how they calculated the range of float mentioned below.

[image: Ranges of different datatypes in c++]

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Comment: You should see IEEE 754 standard to see how float and double values are epresented in memory in most systems.

Comment: If you want to know how - read about representation of float numbers in memory. Otherwise use std::numeric_limits

Answer (score 7):

Floating point numbers are stored as an exponent and a fraction within the space available.

For some systems where `float` is implemented as an IEEE 754 value, the results would looks as below.

```
sign : 1 bit
exponent : 8 bits
fraction : 23 bits
```

The exponent allows numbers from 2 ^ (-127)  (2 to the power -127) to 2 ^ 128 ( 2 to the power 128).

Allowing a range of numbers from

5.87747E-39
3.40282E+38

the fraction point gives a fraction such as .12313

Thus with 23 bits of values, the accuracy of a number is about 7 decimal digits or 1.19 E-7

For more details see [wikipedia : IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

On a given system, the `<cfloat>` / `<float.h>` will give the limits.  For non IEEE 754 based representations, you would have to understand how the numbers are stored to calculate the limits.

Comment: C++ doesn't require IEEE-754

Comment: Note, also, that, with an IEEE-754 implementation, `float` and `double` have an implied 1 bit at the top of the fraction, so 23 stored bits means that the fraction is actually 24 bits wide. (Once you get down to the minimum exponent that leading 1 can disappear, but that's getting into subnormals, and it's a separate topic)

Comment: @mksteve Why does no one take the mantissa part into consideration? I think the more correct way of calculating the range is 1.(2^23-1) * 2^128 which is more than just 2^128. Is it an approximation thing?! (sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

`-2^(n-1) to (2^(n-1)-1)` is the formula to calculate the range of data types.

Where n = no.of.bits of the primitive data type.

For example: for the byte data type, n = 8 bits
`-2^(8-1) to (2^(8-1)-1)`
The above calculation will give you -128 to 127. Now, coming to the question of why it’s not 255. The reason is that byte, int, short, and double are signed data types meaning it has half the range below 0 (negative) and half the range above 0 (positive). The first bit represents a sign (+ or -). The remaining bits are 7. That’s why `2^(8-1) = 128`. We take 0 as a positive sign, so the range is `2^(8-1) - 1` for positive numbers. Floating point numbers are stored as an exponent and a fraction within the space available.